# Procedure parameter used into Select (Oracle, PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, parameters, oracle12c

I have procedure to execute Select:

```
PROCEDURE Test  (colValue    IN     VARCHAR2)               
IS
    vINS        VARCHAR2(32000) := 'select * from abc.table where col10 = colValue';        
BEGIN 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vINS;
END;
```

but I'm no sure if parameter **colValue** is used properly into Select,

maybe should be like :=colValue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate the variable ( || ).

**EDIT** : As pointed out by mathguy, since you are using a `VARCHAR2` variable, you need to enclose it with additional quotes.Obviously, for number variables this wouldn't be necessary.

```
  PROCEDURE Test  (colValue    IN     VARCHAR2)               
    IS
        vINS        VARCHAR2(32000) := 'select * from abc.table where col10 = ''' || colValue ||'''';        
    BEGIN 
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vINS;
    END;
```

As it turns out, using bind variables is much efficient in your case. However, **if** you are using TABLE names, COLUMN names dynamically, you must stick to concatenation since

*table and column names cannot be passed as bind variables*

```
vINS  VARCHAR2(32000) := 'select * from abc.table where col10 = :var';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vINS USING colValue;
```

However, It is of no use to run a select statement in `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, if you are not storing the result into a variable or collection.
You could use `REF CURSOR` out variable, print the results.

```
  PROCEDURE Test  (colValue    IN     VARCHAR2, vINS OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)               
    IS
    BEGIN 
        OPEN vINS FOR select * from abc.table where col10 =  colValue;        
    END;


VARIABLE x REFCURSOR;
EXECUTE Test  ('Value',:x);
PRINT x;
```

If you are working in Oracle 12c, you could use `DBMS_SQL.return_result`

```
   PROCEDURE Test  (colValue    IN     VARCHAR2 )             
    IS
    l_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN 
        OPEN vINS FOR select * from abc.table where col10 =  colValue; 
        DBMS_SQL.return_result (l_cursor);

    END;
```

Comment: I want to just run procedure, if it will be insert or update, then the DB will be updated, no necessary to return

Comment: This isn't quite right - you are missing the single-quotes that should be appended around the string `colValue`. You need something like `... = ''' || colValue || ''''`. But even after you fix this, there are two more arguments against this solution; see my Comment under William Robertson's answer, as well as https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @mathguy : xkcd: hilarious!

Answer (score 0):

You should use bind variables, like this:

```
procedure test(colvalue in varchar2)
is
    vins long := 'select * from abc.table where col10 = :b1';
begin
    execute immediate vins using colvalue;
end;
```

(You would probably want to actually do something with the results rather than ignoring them as above, but that is probably for another question. Depending on what this is intended to do, it probably doesn't need to be dynamic either.)

Comment: @4est - this answer is better than the one you marked as "correct" (but it is also more advanced - perhaps you missed the key difference between the two answers). If you write the SQL statement with a bind variable, like William demonstrates here, then the query is parsed only once; any input value you pass in will be passed to the query as a bind variable. If you hard-code the input argument directly into the SQL statement, with concatenation (`||`), the query will be parsed again every time you pass in a different value. Worse, doing it that way opens you to SQL injection, a very bad thing.